# Cast custom type to basic type pointer

Tags: go, pointers, type-conversion

Let's assume I have code like this:

```
type CustomStringType string

var a *CustomStringType

x := CustomStringType("sample string")
a = &x


var b *string
```

and I cannot modify anything in above code.

Now I would like to assign `a` to `b`

I've tried multiple ways like:

```
b = a
b = string(a)
b = a.(string)
b = a.(*string)
```

but none of them really works.

Comment: Use simple type conversion: `b = (*string)(a)`

Comment: @icza Thanks, it seems that's it, I was not aware of such syntax. If you can add this as answer, I will accept this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple type [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
b = (*string)(a)
```

> An *explicit* conversion is an expression of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and `x` is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.

Since the type you want to convert to starts with a `*` operator, it must be parenthesized to avoid ambiguity (e.g. you want to convert to `*string`, and not to `string` and dereference the result).

`(*string)(a)` is a valid conversion, because you want to convert a value from type `*CustomStringType` to `*string`, and the spec allows such conversion with the following rule:

> A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in any of these cases:
>
> - [...]
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), `x`'s type and `T` are pointer types that are not [named types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Types), and their pointer base types are not type parameters but have identical underlying types.

Both `*CustomStringType` and `*string` are unnamed pointer types, and both have `string` as their pointer base types.

Answer (score 1):

You can using [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) from go.dev documents:

> Conversion = Type "(" Expression [ "," ] ")"

But let look at this note

> If the type starts with the operator * or <-, or if the type starts with the keyword func and has no result list, it must be parenthesized when necessary to avoid ambiguity:

So the solution can be:

```
b = (*string)(a)
```